# what do you call someone performing below their potential

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who doesn't know their worth or is under-performing their potential?

Comment: It's not even clear what part of speech you're after. You can use your very own *underperforming*. Or *underperformer*. Or any number of synonyms a good dictionary or thesaurus will supply.

Comment: heh this question is self-referential

Answer (score 1):

The most common term is "***underachiever***".

> [***underachiever***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underachiever): *a person (and especially a student) who fails to achieve his or her potential or does not do as well as expected*.